# Does the coordinator keyspace need to have same replication factor and application's main keyspace

Tags: scalardb

I am using ScalarDB to add ACID support on Cassandra.

If my application's main table has replication factor of 3 and SimpleStrategy, does the `Coordinator` keyspace also need to be the same?

```
CREATE KEYSPACE mykeyspace WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3'} ;

CREATE KEYSPACE coordinator WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3'} ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they should be the same.

You can use the schema tool to generate those for you.
https://github.com/scalar-labs/scalardb/tree/master/tools/schema

Comment: thanks. Sorry I am on Windows so can't use the tool. I create the schema manually.